# Total number of microstates in a system

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics

If we consider a system made of two isolated parts, say A and B where let's say A has 100 particles and B has 100 particles. If the coordinates of ($q$,$p$) specify the microstate of a particle, then while calculating the total number of microstates, why we multiply the microstates of two isolated parts, instead of just adding them i.e why $$\Omega_{total}= \Omega_{A}\Omega_{B} $$ instead of $$\Omega_{total}= \Omega_{A}+\Omega_{B}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each one of the $\Omega_A$ possible arrangements of the first subsystem, there are $\Omega_B$ passible arrangements of the second.  Similarly, if I roll a die with my left hand and a die with my right, the number of possible combinations is not $6+6=12$, but rather $6\cdot 6=36$.